# JavaScript in a WebView

Tags: android

I have a block of html that has javascript embedded in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var paEmbedId = 461745;
var paEmbedWidth = 600;
var paEmbedOemId = 24500;
var paServer = 'http://www.ncataggies.com/';
var paIframe = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ncataggies.com/oemjs/0/PhotoAlbum2009Embed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I put the code inside a text document and run it from a browser(as a HTML file), the code runs perfectly.

How can I do this using a WebView in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`loadData`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) method of `WebView` widget:

```
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
 // ... although note that there are restrictions on what this HTML can do.
 // See the JavaDocs for loadData() and loadDataWithBaseURL() for more info.
```

If JS is not enabled, then you can also enable JS in WebView:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

But before that, you may want to read this from Android:

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not
>   enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is
>   only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine;
>   the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it,
>   and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually
>   want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the
>   Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a
>   WebView.

Comment: you need to enable javascript for wevview

Comment: Also, if you are dealing with javascript then dont forget to add this line before calling loadData.   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: hmm..for some reason, I don't see anything but a white screen, the javascript doesn't appear to be loading.

Comment: It should be working, please copy your code here so we can see what you did. (Your Java code) And also please check your manifest file too.